# Python re.findall from file

Tags: python

I am trying to extract all of the text between two keywords in a text file. The keywords appear multiple times in the file, so I will have multiple blocks of good text.

The input.txt file is this:

```
bad bad keyword1 GOOD DATA keyword2 bad
bad bad bad keyword1 MORE 
GOOD DATA keyword2 bad bad
```

This is not working:

```
import re

f = open('input.txt', 'r')
trim = re.findall('keyword1(.+?)keyword2', f.read())
print trim
```

It returns an empty list:

```
[]
```

Comment: In fact, it works form me with or without re.MULTILINE flag

Comment: Just printed ` GOOD DATA ` for me.

Comment: This will only return an empty list if you run f.read() twice

Comment: You are right it does return GOOD DATA, but it's not getting MORE GOOD DATA. What is the easiest way to grab both?

Comment: re.MULTILINE is wrong flag, the good flag is re.DOTALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s = "bad bad keyword1 GOOD DATA " \
    "keyword2 bad bad bad bad " \
    "keyword1 MORE GOOD DATA " \
    "keyword2 bad bad"

for i in re.findall('keyword1(.*?)keyword2', s, re.DOTALL):
    print(i)
```

Comment: The question states "in a text file", not from a multiline string.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to grab all the data you should use re.DOTALL flag:

```
trim = re.findall('keyword1(.+?)keyword2', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

Usually the dot character means to get all chars but \n. With the DOTALL attribute the engine also matches \n for the dot character.

Output:

```
[' GOOD DATA ', ' MORE \nGOOD DATA ']
```

Comment: very nice, I did not know about re.DOTALL!

Comment: By default, '.' does not include new line characters.  DOTALL forces it to include the new line.

Comment: Yes, added the explanation on the response, thanks for feedback